# Match if string starts with n digits and no more

Tags: python, python-re

I have strings like `6202_52_55_1959.txt`

I want to match those which starts with 3 digits and no more.

So `6202_52_55_1959.txt` should not match but `620_52_55_1959.txt` should.

```
import re
regexp = re.compile(r'^\d{3}')
file = r'6202_52_55_1959.txt'
print(regexp.search(file))

<re.Match object; span=(0, 3), match='620'> #I dont want this example to match
```

How can I get it to only match if there are three digits and no more following?

Comment: ^(\d{3})+\D does this help you ? It just say that it capture everything that begin with 3 digit and then any non digit character

Comment: Yes, that also works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [negative lookahead](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html):

```py
regexp = re.compile(r'^\d{3}(?!\d)')
```

Comment: Downvoted as being a copy of my answer.  Note that `(?!\d)` is identical to `(?=\D)`, and my answer works as well as yours (though I posted first).

Comment: No, they are not identical. Please see my comment on your answer for details. Congratulation on posting first, by the way!

Answer (score 0):

Use the pattern `^\d{3}(?=\D)`:

```py
inp = ["6202_52_55_1959.txt", "620_52_55_1959.txt"]
for i in inp:
    if re.search(r'^\d{3}(?=\D)', i):
        print("MATCH:    " + i)
    else:
        print("NO MATCH: " + i)
```

This prints:

```
NO MATCH: 6202_52_55_1959.txt
MATCH:    620_52_55_1959.txt
```

The regex pattern used here says to match:

```regex
^       from the start of the string
\d{3}   3 digits
(?=\D)  then assert that what follows is NOT a digit (includes end of string)
```

Comment: Down-voted because this solution won't work if the string being searched is only 3 characters long (and they're all digits).

Comment: My answer covers all your mentioned edge cases.

Comment: When I run `python -c 'import re; print(re.search(r"^\d{3}(?=\D)", "123"))'`, I get `None`. When I run `python -c 'import re; print(re.search(r"^\d{3}(?!\d)", "123"))'`, I get `<re.Match ...`